# How do I edit a links published date?

Tags: links

I mean the links in in the admin panel.  There is no option to edit published date.[image]

EDIT:  added screenshot of link.  Please don't down vote me, I know how to edit posts published date.

Comment: please add more details to your question.

Comment: What else do you need to know! The links in the actual admin panel not content editor, under media and posts.

Comment: Ok, what links you are refering to is clear. But where did you get that links had a published date? You may use a Custom Post Type instead..

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, [Links are being removed altogether with WordPress](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307) (either in 3.5 or the next release).

Second, there is no concept of a "published date for these kind of links.  There's no place in the database for it at all.  There is a "date updated," but that's just to record when you last made a change - it's meant to be a way to log changes and is specifically not meant to be editable:

[image: WordPress Links table]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to edit the publish date via admin panel for posts, post types and pages.

Just go to the post or page that you want to change the publish date on and go here to your publish box.

[image]

Click on edit next to the publish date.

[image]

Change the date. Click ok and then click publish or update.

Comment: No for links not post. I think link lives under posts and media.